# Getting an error while playing a video using VideoView in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

In my application I want to show a video by online streaming but video does not start and I am getting an error "Sorry this video can not be played" and logcat error is

```
couldn't open file on client side trying server side and mediaplayer error (1,-1004)
```

what does that mean.

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that you have added INTERNET permission in your manifest.

Next, Check what is the extension of your video format.

[here](http://www.wondershare.com/convert-video-audio/android-video-format.html) you can check what files Android phones and tablets support, with both codec and filename extension information provided.

if you want to play videos on Android, find a multi-format video player or convert videos to Android compatible formats.

Comment: yes i have added internet permission in my android manifest file and the link of the video is http://cdn.videodetective.net/svideo-mp4-750/mp4/750/119/005011.mp4?c=9091234&r=750&s=5011&d=134&sub=&ref=na&fmt=4&e=20130207110215&h=0c5f8127c868ba507cf2c

Comment: is there any problem with my url of that video